# Retrieve TextTable from TextTableCursor with LibreOffice 4.1 Writer Basic

Tags: macros, libreoffice, word-processor, libreoffice-basic

I would like to write a macro that works on the selected table.

### Selection in a table

When I select a table, the object that `ThisComponent.CurrentSelection` returns is of type `SwXTextTableCursor`. I will refer to it generically as *TextTableCursor*.

According to `DBG_methods` it provides methods to traverse through the selected cells and merge or split the cells, but it doesn't seem to provide a way to access the actual table itself. Conversely, `ThisComponent.TextTables` returns the tables.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to determine if some cells or all of a table is selected.

### Question

Is there any way to retrieve the TextTable(s) from TextTableCursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current selected TextTable use

```
ThisComponent.CurrentController.ViewCursor.TextTable
```